# Prove that $(\sin x + \cos x)(6 - \sin x)<9$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

Is there any elementary way to prove that $(\sin x + \cos x)(6 - \sin x)<9$?

I've noticed that $(\sin x + \cos x)$ has to be positive so $x \in\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{3\pi}{4}\right)$ and then $(6 - \sin x)\in\left(6-\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2},6+ \dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}\right)$ but since $(\sin x + \cos x) \in\left(0, \sqrt2\right]$ the maximum possible value of $(\sin x + \cos x)(6 - \sin x)$ can be $(6+ \dfrac{\sqrt2}{2}) * \sqrt2 = 1+6\sqrt2$ which is greater than $9$.

My second attempt was to find the derivative, but I couldn't find its roots.

Comment: Try applying the AM-GM theorem.

Answer (score 5):

Using the product-to-sum identity $\sin\theta\sin\phi = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(\theta - \phi) - \cos(\theta + \phi))$ to simplify:
\begin{align*}
  & (\sin x + \cos x)(6 - \sin x) \\
= & \sqrt{2}\sin(x + \pi/4)(6 - \sin x) \\
= & 6\sqrt{2}\sin(x + \pi/4) - \sqrt{2}\sin x\sin(x + \pi/4) \\
= & 6\sqrt{2}\sin(x + \pi/4) - \sqrt2\times \frac{\cos(\pi/4) - \cos(2x+\pi/4)}{2} \\
= & 6\sqrt{2}\sin(x + \pi/4) + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos(2x + \pi/4) - \frac{1}{2} \\
\leq & 6\sqrt{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \\
= & 8.69\ldots < 9.  
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

**Proof 1**: Note that $\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt 2 \, \sin (x + \pi/4) \le \sqrt 2$
and $6 - \sin x > 0$.

If $\sin x \ge 0$, we have
$(\sin x + \cos x)(6 - \sin x) \le \sqrt 2 \cdot (6 - \sin x)
\le \sqrt 2 \cdot 6 < 9$.

If $\sin x < 0$, we have
$\sin x + \cos x \le \cos x \le 1$ and thus $(\sin x + \cos x)(6 - \sin x) 
\le 6 - \sin x \le 7 < 9$.

We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

**Proof 2**: $(a - b)^2 \ge 0$ yields $ab \le \frac{(a + b)^2}{4}$ for all real numbers $a, b$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 (\sin x + \cos x)(6 - \sin x) &= \frac14 \cdot 4(\sin x + \cos x)\cdot (6 - \sin x)\\
  &\le \frac14 \cdot \frac{(4\sin x + 4\cos x + 6 - \sin x)^2}{4}\\
  &=\frac{(3\sin x + 4\cos x + 6)^2}{16} \\
  &\le \frac{(5 + 6)^2}{16}\\
  & = \frac{121}{16} = 7.5625
\end{align*}
where we have used $(3\sin x + 4\cos x)^2
\le (3^2 + 4^2)(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x) = 25$ (C-S inequality)
to get $-5 \le 3 \sin x + 4\cos x \le 5$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
(\sin x + \cos x)(6 - \sin x) & = 6 \cos x + 6 \sin x - \sin^2 x - \sin x \cos x \\ &= 6 \cos x + 6 \sin x - \dfrac{1}{2} (1 - \cos(2x) ) - \dfrac{1}{2} \sin(2x)\\
&= 6 \cos x + 6 \sin x + \dfrac{1}{2} (\cos(2x) - \sin(2x) ) - \dfrac{1}{2} \\
&\le 6 \sqrt{2} + \dfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{2} - \dfrac{1}{2} = 8.692388 \\ &\lt 9 \end{split} \end{equation} $